# What was the original rhyming scheme of "Do not shun me..."?

Tags: poetry, belarusian-language, like-water-like-fire, francisak-bahusevic

The poem *Do Not Shun Me...* starts as follows:

> Do not shun me, my lord, nor recoil
> Because callouses all my hands cover;
> For such sis the badget of a hard toil,
> And will not defile you, no never.
> 'Tis a medal of suffering and working,
> And no plague-spot will meet thy inspection;
> Then give me thy hand, without shirking,
> Since mine is not stained by infection.
> Ah, uncover thy head with more zeal,
> When I bow to the ground thus responding,
> *Thy* head I'll not pluck off, nor steal,
> And with mine, Sir, thou'lt not be absconding.

In the English at least, more or less every other sentence ends in a rhyme ("recoil... toil", "working... shirking", "inspection... infection", "zeal... steal" and "responding... absconding"). Was this also the case in the original language?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's the same ABAB pattern.

Original on [wikisource](https://be.wikisource.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%B5_%D1%86%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%8F):

> Не цурайся мяне, панічок,
>
> Што далонь пакрываюць мазолі;
>
> Мазоль — працавітых значок,
>
> Не заразе цябе ён ніколі.